# Wordpress Media Not Showing Images

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress media was working fine till i uploaded an image. I uploaded an image and it was stuck on 100% crunching. After that it is not showing any image. I have installed Filebird plugin also to check whether the images are showing or not. Images are available in the wpcontent/uploads.
[Attachment of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPFYa.png)